# Specify Candidate Key In grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

How can i specify "name" as primary key...by specifying through domain class groovy file.. i'm working in fedora as OS and through terminal (not using ggts or any tools) and using database as MySQL

```
class Department {

    String name
    String description
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change which field is your primary key, you can use the `id` mapping entry like so:

```
class Department {
    String name

    static mapping = {
        id name: 'name', generator: 'assigned'
    }
}
```

You can read more details about the options on the id entry in the [Grails Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html).